# IIS WAS error with eventId 5172 causing AppPool instability

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, was7

I have an intermittent problem with an IIS site going offline a few times per month.  The Event logs show the following errors:

```
Source :  WAS  
EventID:  5053  
Message:  The Windows Process Activation Service received a change
          notification, but was unable to process it correctly.  

Source :  WAS  
EventID: 5172  
Message: The Windows Process Activation Service encounter an error 
         trying to read the configuration data from file 
         \\?\UNC\domain\dfs\iis-config-folder\applicationHost.config
```

Followed by errors

```
Source : IIS-APPHOSTSVC  
EventID: 9012 (invalid applicationHost.config),
         9006 (processing config errors), and often 
         9000 (SID mapping)
```

Does the need for SID resolution trigger these events?  The site is configured to use anonymous authentication only so I'm not sure why SID mapping would ever be needed.

I have tried but cannot find good info on configuring WAS.

Running IIS 8.5 on Win2012R2.

Comment: Is this a single web server or a multiple server setup? Do you have shared configuration enabled? (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771871(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: yes, good point. we do use a shared config and it _is_ at the location specified in the error (I edited the question to fix this).  So, how could that cause the problem?